# "Add More" button in theme-settings.php

Tags: forms

The following code is a snippet from the [examples for developers](http://drupal.org/project/examples) project:

```
    function form_example_tutorial_9_add_name($form, &$form_state) {
        // Everything in $form_state is persistent, so we'll just use
        // $form_state['add_name']

        $form_state['num_names']++;

        // Setting $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE causes the form to be rebuilt again.
        $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
    }

    function form_example_tutorial_9_remove_name($form, &$form_state) {
      if ($form_state['num_names'] > 1) {
        $form_state['num_names']--;
      }

      // Setting $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE causes the form to be rebuilt again.
      $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
    }

    /**
     * Validate function for form_example_tutorial_9().
     *
     * Adds logic to validate the form to check the validity of the new fields,
     * if they exist.
     */
    function form_example_tutorial_9_validate($form, &$form_state) {

      for ($i = 1; $i <= $form_state['num_names']; $i++) {
        $year_of_birth = $form_state['values']['name'][$i]['year_of_birth'];

        if ($year_of_birth && ($year_of_birth < 1900 || $year_of_birth > 2000)) {
          form_set_error("name][$i][year_of_birth", t('Enter a year between 1900 and 2000.'));
        }
      }
    }

    /**
     * Submit function for form_example_tutorial_9().
     */
    function form_example_tutorial_9_submit($form, &$form_state) {
      $output = t("Form 9 has been submitted.");
      for ($i = 1; $i <= $form_state['num_names']; $i++) {
        $output .= t("@num: @first @last (@date)... ", array('@num' => $i, '@first' => $form_state['values']['name'][$i]['first'],
          '@last' =>  $form_state['values']['name'][$i]['last'], '@date' =>  $form_state['values']['name'][$i]['year_of_birth']));
      }
      drupal_set_message($output);
    }
```

I've been trying to implement field with an "Add More" button (and "Remove Previous" button if more then one field exists) into theme-settings.php based off of the above code, however I'm not having much luck. Does anyone know how to create this functionality within THEMENAME_form_system_theme_settings_alter? Any help is greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: how did you try to do it?

Comment: I tried adding the code inside of form_example_tutorial_9_remove_name and form_example_tutorial_9_add_name to THEMENAME_form_system_theme_settings_alter inside of theme-settings.php